# Cancelling Parse retries on bad internet connection

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nstimer, background-process

I'm trying to do something quite simple : Stopping a `parse.com` query after a few seconds, with an `NSTimer`. I've read after some reasearch it's a good "trick" to use.

Here is how I create my timer :

```
   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(stopRetries:)
                                                        userInfo:@{@"query":query}
                                                         repeats:NO];
```

Because i'm running this on a background thread (and outside a viewcontroller class), the timer is inside a `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue());`

But whatever I do, I cannot stop the query, because `[query cancel]` doesn't do anything. I can't pass it in the `userInfo` of the timer. Breakpoints show it has an address and is "there" but it looks like junk inside.

What can I be doing wrong and what should I be doing instead?

My main goal is to make the `parse.com` query stop faster than 30 seconds, and warn the user with an alert.

Comment: Can you explain more about "I cannot stop the query, because query cancel doesn't do anything"?  The docs advertise this as canceling the current network request and not calling the callbacks.  You should have no expectation that you'd see this effect manifest by inspecting the query pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this   `[self performSelector:@selector(abc) withObject:nil afterDelay:6.0];`

or

You can Invalidate the timer

Comment: but how can I NOT perform the selector if the request happens to be fast enough? (aka most of the time)

Comment: You could set a `BOOL finishedQuery` or something like that to true when your query finished and in your cancel method test `if(!finishedQuery) {}`.

Comment: I'm in an NSObject subclass, not a viewcontroller, i'm not sure how i can have a BOOL that both methods could read.

But either way, my query doesn't cancel with [query cancel];, this doesn't make sense at all :(

Comment: This idea looks reasonable to me, and you could use NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget to cancel, or you could just let it cancel (there should be no down-side to canceling a completed query).  The bigger issue with your question is your comment that cancel doesn't work.  The evidence you offer (that the pointer looks wrong when you inspect it) leads me to think that you have the wrong expectation about how cancel should manifest.  The doc promises only that the network request will be canceled and callbacks will not be called.  Are you observing otherwise?

Comment: My comment above may be unclear:  to restate, you can use performSelector to setup a delayed cancel of the query, and you can use cancelPreviousPerform... **to cancel the delayed query cancel**, but (a) you probably can just cancel the query after delay unconditionally, and (b) you seem to be mistaken about what query cancel does.